# Prove that $a+b+1 = 0$

Tags: polynomials

The polynomials $x^2+ax+b$ and $x^2+bx+a$ have common factors.prove that $a+b+1=0$.

My attempt- I could do nothing other than dividing the polynomials to get  $x^2+bx+a$=$x^2+ax+b+bx-ax+a-b$.Please help me what to do.

Comment: Let $p$ and $q$ be common factors of the polynomials, then substitute to get 2 equations.

Comment: hope you can solve  questions more difficult than this one.

Comment: @HassanMuhammad currently i study in 9.Hope that one day i will also become like you!

Comment: I pray for you to be not like me, but ahead of me.

Comment: go ahead ask your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17198/discussion-between-hassan-muhammad-and-snehil-sinha).

Comment: The question should read "have a common factor", not "have common factors".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p$ and $q$ are common factors of the polynomials, then $$p^2+pb+a=p^2+ap+b$$ and $$q^2+qb+a=q^2+aq+b$$ So, $(b-a)p=b-a$ and $(b-a)q=b-a$, this shows that $p=q=1$ Substituting $p=q=1$ in each of the two equations yeilds  $a+b+1=0$

Comment: $p=q=1$ are not the common factors.

Comment: The polynomials have _one_ common factor, which must be of the form $x-c$ for some $c$. What you have written here makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

If $x-c$ is the common  factor,

$x-c$ will divide $(x^2+bx+a)-(x^2+ax+b)=(b-a)(x-1)\implies c=1$

If $x^2+bx+a=(x-1)(x-d),$

$\iff x^2+bx+a=x^2-x(d+1)+d$

Comparing the constants & the coefficients of $x,$

$ d=a,b=-(d+1)=-(a+1)$

Comment: upvote thank you too for help.

Comment: The best answer would combine the first half of this one with the second half of NumThcurious's answer.

Answer (score 0):

let $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$ and $g(x)=x^2+bx+a$.

If the 2 polynomials have a common factor, then there exists an $x$ such that can write $$ f(x)=g(x)$$
Then we obtain, 
$ax+b=bx+a$,
which implies $x=1$ thereby $x-1$ is the common factor of the $2$ polynomials for all $a-b \neq 0$.

Since $x-1$ is a common factor of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, then $f(1)=g(1)=0$. By replacing $x=1$ in both functions, the result is simply identical: $$ 1+b+a=1+a+b=0$$